# Ember Data : New record with default value from API

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I can use `App.Model.createRecord()` to get a *new* record.

What I need is to populate the attributes and relationships of this new record with value from the remote API : the API respond to `GET /models/new` with the json corresponding to a new record (it does not have an ID).

Anyone knows how can I do this ?

Comment: Honest question: Can't you pass the values from the JSON as the argument of `createRecord`? Something like `App.Model.createRecord({property: json.property, ...})`

Comment: I will try something like that but I believe it won't work for relationships. In fact my first need is to initialize some embedded `hasMany` relationships with objects.

Comment: you can also try `var x = App.Model.createRecord({property: json.property, ...}); x.set('objectProperty', App.OtherModel.createRecord({ json.objectProperty.property, ...});`

Comment: I'm trying this but it is difficult to implement and not a 'good way' to do this because I cannot use serializer mappings : the json I got is serialized by the API (keys are underscored) and `createRecord` expect a hash with the attribute name (camelCase). For underscored / camelCase I can do this manually but not for the keys I specified manually in the mapping.